# Hibernate SQL query compare only date in timestamp field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date

I have to get the list of records based on `last_update_At`from mysql DB. It is a `timestamp` field in mysql. From my java code am passing the date in the below format.

```
 Mon May 06 20:05:32 IST 2019
```

In mysql `last_update_At` having the following format `2019-05-06 19:46:00`. I want to fetch this record only on the date comparasion not with time also.

Please find my hibernate query below :

```
 @Query("select u from User u where u.lastLoginAt <= :thresholdDate")
 public List<User> findLastLoginDaysDifference(@Param("thresholdDate") Date thresholdDate);
```

with this query is not able to fetch the record.

Comment: Cast it to date before comparing. That is the safest way to handle date only comparison

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hibernate cast operator:

```
select u from User u where cast(u.lastLoginAt as date) <= :thresholdDate
```